# Device storage consumption

Tags: android-management-api

Using the Android Management API, I'm trying to collect the device's storage consumption information.

I found some information in memoryInfo and memoryEvents.

In memoryInfo there is an attribute called "totalInternalStorage" and in "memoryEvents there is" an event of type "INTERNAL_STORAGE_MEASURED".

Questions:

1. Please, what does the value shown in "totalInternalStorage" mean? Does it mean the total amount of storage available?
2. What does the value shown in "INTERNAL_STORAGE_MEASURED" mean? Does it mean the consumed value of internal storage?
3. How is a "memoryEvents" fired? Can I collect this information at any time or do I have to wait for Google to do it in their time?

I took a test and collected the following information:

- totalInternalStorage = 0.1 GB
- memoryEvents = 4 GB (INTERNAL_STORAGE_MEASURED, 3 days ago)

This information, to me, is very confusing and that's why I need your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. totalInternalStorage in the memoryInfo is the measurement of the [root](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getRootDirectory()) of the total "system" partition storage
2. [MemoryEvent](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#memoryevent) returns 3 value per event eventType , createTime, and byteCount. in the test you made the value you receive is as follows

- eventType  - [INTERNAL_STORAGE_MEASURED](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#memoryeventtype) it means that the memory measured was the Internal Storage or  read-only system partition
- byteCount  - 4 GB is the number of free bytes in the medium or in your internal storage
- createTime - 3 days ago , it is the day where the event occurred

3. The memoryInfo measurements are taken asynchronously on the device either when a change is detected or when there's a periodic refresh of the device status. You can check the status everytime you call device.get()