# Device "memoryEvents"

Tags: android-management-api

Using the Android Management API, I would like to understand how the device's "memoryEvents" works.

I know I have to turn on this events using the policy's properties:

> statusReportingSettings.setMemoryInfoEnabled(true);

After that, I will receive memory events into the device property "memoryEvents".
My questions are:

1. What's the periodicity where Google collects this information?
2. Will this list is expanded to infinity?
3. Should I worry about this list getting too big?
4. Can I clean this list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68625944) for more info with regards to memoryEvents. But to answer your questions

1. No particular periodicity, it happens whenever a [MemoryEventType](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#memoryeventtype) is happening.
2. The events retrieved are not exhaustive and focus on anything that triggered a request to get free space in RAM, free space in internal storage, whether an external storage device was connected/removed and how much space there was. So it's quite limited in a way and shouldn't be too consuming in terms of list size, so the answer here is that the list can in theory expand to infinity, unless of course there are millions of those events which would be unlikely! If that was the case, then I suppose you would hit the JSON limit of what can be returned.
3. I don't believe so unless you're talking of a device where external devices keep being connected/removed or apps where memoryEvents keep happening (e.g: you constantly ask for what's the free RAM or space left on a given device).
4. Good question but I don't think it's possible as that would be returned as soon as the device is enrolled. If it's un-enrolled, that list would be reset I suppose.