# How to get device memory via Android Management API

Tags: android, go, android-management-api

I want to get memory from my device, I use [golang lib](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/androidenterprise/v1) for it. My device has 16gb memory, now free 5.3gb and filled 10.7gb.

[image]

After device enrolling, I see that device has 2762690560 bytes for **total internal storage**.

[image]

I send [get command](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get) to get [memory event](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#MemoryEvent)
And I have: 
EXTERNAL_STORAGE_DETECTED - 12061962240 
INTERNAL_STORAGE_MEASURED - 43319296 
EXTERNAL_STORAGE_MEASURED - 5709090816

total internal storage - 2762690560
info about total internal storage from google doc.
[image]

So my problem is that I can't understand how to calculate these event Types to get correct memory data for device, and is it possible to do in this way? Maybe I can send some ADB command to device via Android Management API?

Answer (score 0):

[MemoryEvent](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#memoryevent) returns 3 values per event, `eventType`, `createTime`, and `byteCount`. To get these values, you first need to include the [statusReportingSettings](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#statusreportingsettings) on your policy and set `memoryInfoEnabled: true`. You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68625944) for more information with regards to memoryEvents.

Comment: It's already done, I enable it.